# получение статуса запроса rtk-query endpoint-а в thunk (смотреть setEqualResultThunk)

Tags: redux

В rtk-query есть методы.

```
endpoint.matchFulfilled
endpoint.matchRejected
```

но как они работают не смог разобратся

```js
санка которая юзает нижную санку:

export const setEqualResultThunk: TAction = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const expression = [''];
    const { payload } = await dispatch(addExpressionThunk(expression));
    //... действия
    //СОБСТВЕННО ВОПРОС: как то по адекватнее прервать дальнейшие действия если есть ошибка
    if (payload && typeof payload !== 'string' && 'error' in payload) {
      return;
    }

    //... действия
  };
};

санка которая юзает rtk-query:

export const addExpressionThunk = createAppAsyncThunk(
  'expressions/addExpression',
  async (expression: string[], { dispatch }) => {
    // const date = getDate({ config: ['y', 'm', 'd'] });
    const date = '';

    return dispatch(
      expressionsApi.endpoints.addExpression.initiate({
        date,
        expression,
      }),
    );
  },
);


конечная точка:

const baseApiWithTag = baseApi.enhanceEndpoints({
  addTagTypes: ['Expressions'],
});

export const expressionsApi = baseApiWithTag.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getExpressions: builder.query<RExpressionResponse[], void>({
      query: () => 'expressions',
      providesTags: (result) =>
        result
          ? [
              ...result.map(({ _id }) => ({ type: 'Expressions', id: _id } as const)),
              { type: 'Expressions', id: 'LIST' },
            ]
          : [{ type: 'Expressions', id: 'LIST' }],
    }),
    addExpression: builder.mutation<RExpressionResponse, { expression: string[]; date: string }>({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: 'expressionsX',
        method: 'PUT',
        body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (_, error) => {
        return error ? [] : [{ type: 'Expressions', id: 'LIST' }];
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```